How can I add a sub panel to detached garage
When building my detached garage, contractors simply ran 6/2 wire to in buried conduit. I’d like to add a sub panel in it so I can have breakers and install a 30A RV outlet at some point. All the panels I can find use 2 hot leads. Everything will be 120v. How can I best add another hot side to the wiring?

1 - Need to find out (a) what type and size of conduit they installed; 2 - Need to find out what type of cable (6/2 normally means cable) or wire (could be two individual 6 AWG wires) they installed; do not assume everything will be 120V - that's fine for standard 30A RV and for lights/receptacles, but what about EV charging? But first: conduit size and cable/wire type.

Sounds like sketchy contractors. What is the 6/2 cable connected to at each end NOW? Not having a subpanel NOW means it's either a big fat wire to carry 20A on, or they did something that should have failed inspection. If they used conduit all the way (not direct bury with a bit of conduit at each end) you should be able to pull the cable out and pul wires in. On the other hand, usually the only reason you'd see cable in conduit here would be if most of it is direct-buried and that's just damage protection at the ends...
